# Rspec: How to test that a worker having the sidekiq_option lock: :until_executed isn't enqueued twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, sidekiq-unique-jobs

I'd like to test my worker with Rspec and the gem [sidekiq-uniq-job](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs#your-first-worker).

Let's say I have this job :

```rb
class TestJob < ApplicationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: 'test_queue', lock: :until_executed

  def perform
    puts "Hello World !"
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to test it with the following test for instance :

```rb
it "doesn't enqueue a job to send an email to the rider" do
  TestJob.perform_async
  TestJob.perform_async
  expect(TestJob.jobs.size).to eq(1)
end
```

This would allow me to be sure that my job will never be queued more than once.

How would you do it ??

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to test the 3rd party libraries' machinery. All you have to test is that your job definition contains the proper lock option - everything else is the gem's responsibility. But if you still insist... 1st of all ensure you are using `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` mode (not inline or even disabled) ([docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing)), everything else should be quite straightforward then. Also, you can play around [this matcher](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq/blob/develop/lib/rspec/sidekiq/matchers/have_enqueued_job.rb) (might be overkill)